# why are the Bisection and Newton Method for finding roots complementary to each other?

Tags: optimization, roots, newton-raphson

my lecture note states that the bisection and newton method for finding roots are most of the time complementary to each other but I can not figure out why. I have basic understanding of both of the methods but I don't see them as being complementary to each other. Can anyone please explain this to me.

Thank you very much

Comment: What would "complementary" mean? That when one works well, the other one doesn't?

Comment: No, it means one would complete the other

Comment: They form a nice hunting team, one slow and steady, the other awfully quick but distractable. But once Bisection puts her on the right track, Newton usually can be counted on to finish things quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To complete what André Nicolas said:

The bisection is slower (it converges linearly) but it converges globally (which means any starting point works).

On the other hand, Newton is quick (it converges quadratically in most cases), but does not converge globally, a bad starting point will not find the wanted solution.

Comment: That's giving bisection a little bit too much credit: the point is that bisection can tell you whether it will converge when you start, whereas Newton's method cannot.